# Error while pull from git - insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects

Tags: git

I have git error: "insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects" every time I make "git pull origin develop".

```
    remote: Counting objects: 70, done.
    remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
    remote: Total 42 (delta 35), reused 42 (delta 35)
    error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database     .git/objects

    fatal: failed to write object
    fatal: unpack-objects failed
```

Comment: Obvious question: Do you *have* access rights to the files on disk?

Comment: Check the permissions of the `.git/objects` file. It sounds like you may have mistakenly used `sudo` at some point in the past and given ownership to `root` rather than to yourself.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem @ChrisHayes But which .git/objects file? Where is that file/directory?

Comment: @pedroremedios `.git` is a directory which exists at the base of every git repo.

Answer (score 326, accepted):

Assuming @ChrisHayes is right about an accidental sudo, this should fix it. From inside your repository:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.git"
```

**Update**: for those of you getting the `illegal group name` error, try this instead:

```
sudo chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.git"
```

Comment: What does `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` do? I was able to fix the issue just by using `chown -R user:user` on the top-level directory of my repo.

Comment: @MattK this will get the top-level directory of your repo, so the command will work regardless of where in your repo you currently are. If you're already in the root you can just run `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER .git`

Comment: I get: `Sorry, user myuser is not allowed to execute '/bin/chown' ...`

Comment: I get:

    `illegal group name`

Comment: I was using the wrong username. The command worked. Thank you.

Comment: it also happened to me after an accidental sudo before. changing the owner/group fixed it

Comment: I am a little late to the party here, but I tried executing the second option above after getting the Operation not permitted for the first option and 'rev' was not a valid command, try revert. Tried revert and I received a fatal: bad revision 'parse' and chown: invalid option -- '1'. Also where you have $(id -u):$(id -g) am I typing anything unique to my own repo? I am fairly new to this.

Comment: @Jack Armstrong It sounds like you may have typed `rev -parse` with a space. The correct command is `rev-parse` (no space)

Answer (score 28):

Go to project's root directory and run below commands to fix this issue,

```
cd .git/objects
sudo chown -R yourname:yourgroup *
```

Answer (score 3):

Mine was a stupid mistake... the right username and group were set, but www-data was the account accessing it. The directory was owned by vaindil:www-data, but permissions were 755 so www-data couldn't write to it. Fixed it with:

```
$ sudo chmod -R 775 /path/to/repo
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOT A GOOD PRACTICE (Just an alternative)**

I am using Ubuntu and faced the same problem. To solve it, I simply switched user to root and I see no further error.

```
$su
password
```

Then,

```
$git pull origin master
```

Recommended way: CHANGE THE PERMISSION OF THE DIRECTORY

Comment: This will work (as will `sudo`), but it is best practice to avoid running commands as root wherever possible.

Comment: @dwurf Thank you for the comment. It was just an alternative to the answer above. :)

Comment: NOT A SOLUTION as well - you dont want to use your repo as sudo.

Comment: @WaxCage Yes, but do you see the big bold text already there? :)

Answer (score 0):

remove .git from the url, if you are trying to clone a public repository from github.

example:

From: https://github.com/example/repository.git
To: https://github.com/example/repository